# Permanently removing files from hard drive

Tags: c, assembly, filesystems, hard-drive, delete-file

I am wondering how to go about writing a program to permanently remove files from my hard drive. I know that my program needs to at least have the same functionality as "rm" in terms of removing the system's links to the data, but I also am interested in how I go about nullifying (entirely) the data on the disk.

I am pretty sure that **C** and assembly will provide this low level functionality, but I'm not really sure how to even start trying to access parts of the disk, or track down the locations of different fragments of a file on the disk.

I know this might seem like kind of a big project due to my lack of knowledge on filesystems, but I'm just trying to learn. I'm aware that I'll need to learn more about hard drives and what type of drive I'm specifically trying to work with. But any help/links you could provide would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that you will be able to do this directly, without writing kernel-space code.  The OS is responsible for the low-level access to the hard disk.

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but to permanently remove a file I think you mean that it won't be recovered, so if you rewrite each byte of your file with junk data, and remove it afterwards that should do it.

Comment: @AtoMerZ: that *might* do it, but for example on Windows Vista it will *not* do it if there's shadow storage for that drive, and your file has been caught up in a system restore point. This is obvious in the sense that system restore wouldn't work at all if overwriting a file permanently deleted the old contents, but it's non-obvious in that if you want to shred a file, then you have to understand what files have shadow copies.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, true, but I don't think any program could track that, could it?

Comment: @AtoMerZ: A portable program couldn't do anything, but on Windows it's possible at least to identify when shadow copies exist. I don't know the details of the Windows APIs to do it, but things like "Shadow Explorer" manage.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to use a program like [scrub](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scrub). The only problem, is that for many file system it does not work.

To come up with a generic solution is probably going to be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay if you open the file, get the file size and then write n null bytes to the file that you want to delete (where n is the number of bytes).

Afterwards just delete the file. All data will be lost and if someone recovers the file-node all he can see is a bunch of zeroes.

That said: I'm sure that some people here will tell you that you have to wipe the file with zeros (or some other pattern) at least 10 to 15 times to really remove all traces of the content. erase the file once for ever.

This is an urban legend. Don't trust them. Noone, not even the guys from the CSI tv-series can recover a file that has been wiped once.

Comment: CSI guys can "enhance" the 1x1 pixel portion of a security camera frame showing the eye of the victim, upscaling it up to a gazillion megapixels image from which you can see the reflection of the killer on the cornea, so I'm quite sure they could retrieve data even from a hard disk that has been thrown into the Sun. :)

Comment: Okay awesome, this is what I figured would be done but I wasn't sure on whether a fragmented file would be saved back to the exact same locations on the disk. Thanks.

Comment: @Matteo They can also make a GUI application in Visual Basic to track the killers IP...http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkDD03yeLnU

Comment: @Nils: still, as said in a comment to @yan's answer, things aren't so easy, since some filesystems and the hardware do not always overwrite in-place, journaling can leave traces around, and drives do not always really flush changes immediately.

Comment: Problem, some filesystems do copy on write, for example ZFS and BTRFS both do it, writing over a file with 0s might just fill some other previously unused blocks with 0s rather than the blocks that have the file data in them, obviously this is not what you want for secure delete.

Comment: Furthermore, on either a compressing filesystem or a filesystem supporting sparse files, overwriting with zeros might result in a file occupying very little disk space, so the original (less-compressible) data may not be overwritten. And on journalling filesystems you're out of luck, it may be impossible by design to permanently delete anything. It's difficult-to-impossible to recover a *disk sector* that has been overwritten once, but it may be very easy indeed to recover a *file* that has been.

Comment: This answer is only valid for specific file systems. It is very likely that a modern file system will not place the new data at the same location.

Comment: "No one can recover a file that has been wiped once." Strong statement. Care to back that up with a link?